# Restaurar usuarios de phpmyadmin con XAMPP en windows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Buenas a todos! Tengo el siguiente problemón, borre accidentalmente todos los usuarios desde el phpmyadmin y ahora no puedo ingresar mas porque no existe ningun usuario. COmo puedo restaurar todos los usuarios perdidos? no quiero perder mi base de datos :( AYUDA URGENTE :((

Comment: si te sirvio mi respuesta, porfavor marcala como correcta o si encontraste la respuesta correcta  por aparte, ponla y marcala como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

primero que todo calma, segundo entiendo que tienes algo de conocimiento acerca de la jerarquia de archivos entonces entiendes algo de donde estan los archivos y ejecutables necesarios, y tercero entiendes ingles,

aqui la solucion https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124871/deleted-mysql-root-user-using-phpmyadmin-how-to-restore

por favor lee la respuesta marcada como correcta

basicamente lo que hay q hacer es para el servicio de mysql y arrancarlo de nuevo en un tipo de `modo seguro` luego recrear el usuario root y darle los privilegios necesarios. una vez hecho esto cierras la conexcion e iniciar el servicio de mysql normalmente y usas el usuario root para volver a iniciar y con este crear los demas usuarios.

Si no puedes con este proceso, comenta esta respuesta y te doy hago para q lo hagas manipulando archivos pero no se si aun funciona, ya que una vez lo hice.